# Why don't I need to call next in a Sails.js controller function even if it has an (asynchronous?) database query in its body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, controller, sails.js

Example controller function:

```
getArticles: function(req, res) {        
  Articles.find({}).exec(function(err, articles) {
    res.json(articles) // I guess this part is asynchronous
    // next() here?
  }) 
}
```

I am used to call `next()` at the end of an asynchronously executed block of code. That seems to be different in Sails.js. Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `res.json()` in this instance is the last thing you're asking the server to do. There is no next now.

The `next()` convention in this case is due to the fact that sails runs on top of express.js. `Next()` is the pattern in how express runs through its list of middleware. That is why you would use `next()` in your policies and such because they are middlewhere. `res.json()` however is at the end of the chain, so their is no need to call `next()`.

If you're still confused, google `express middleware next()`

To use return? This example below shows why you would want to use return despite it not being needed. By using `return` we ensure that `res.json('otherStuff')` does not execute.

```
getArticles: function(req, res) {        
  Articles.find({}).exec(function(err, articles) {
   if(true) return res.json(articles)
   res.json('otherStuff')
  }) 
}
```

Comment: What confused me was the `return` in e.g. `return res.send('something')`, which I saw in some example code snippets. This made me think I have to return something. Either through `return` or through `next`.

Comment: `return res.send('something')` though not needed can help ensure that your controller does exit properly. On the chance that you have conditional logic and another `res.send('somethingElse')` the return keyword helps to ensure that you are exiting and do not run the risk of  `res.send('somethingElse') firing. It's good practice to put a return in there is most cases.